# multilanguage source code reformatter / beautifier / pretty-printer

Tags: linux, open-source, offline, source-code, code-beautification

I'm looking for a multi language source code reformatter / beautifier / pretty-printer. Installing and managing a separate tool for each language is quite time-wasting.

It has to support

- C/C++
- Java
- JavaScript
- HTML
- PHP
- Python
- Lua
- and hopefully some other languages I need in the future

It has to work on Linux and I'd like to avoid online solutions and closed-source software.

The most language-agnostic solution I've found so far is [clang-format, which supports C/C++, Java, JavaScript, Objective-C and Protobuf](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Alternatively, [GNU source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Using-source_002dhighlight-as-a-simple-formatter) and [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) claim to support a lot of languages, but it is not clear to me if they can also reformat the source code they process and print it to `stdout`.

For instance I've tried:

```
source-highlight --lang-def=nohilite.lang --output=STDOUT -i test.c
```

and it just outputs the source file surrounded by some HTML tags.

Comment: clang-format does not support HTML, PHP, Python,  Lua and possibly other languages that i need. Installing and managing a separate tool for each of them is quite time-wasting.

Comment: Think of it the other way round: why should someone invent such a tool? A project has 2 or 3 programming languages. Typically a developer invents such a tool because he has a need for it. Why should he develop a tool for 30 programming languages if he has profound knowledge in only 3 of them? Therefore I doubt such a tool is available. The same applies to metrics: you'll hardly find a tool that supports many languages at the same time. Usually you need plugins.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: No programmer tasked with doing standard programming tasks would invent such a tool, agreed.  You have to find somebody that is in the language processing business, and then you get this as a side effect of building language processing tools.  See my answer. (I don't know how you dragged metrics into the conversation, but in fact there's a similar effect for metrics tools).

Comment: I have to add that the code layout should be correctly formatted, for your organisations definition of correct, _in the source files_ __not__ just when you are showing it to someone.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [CodeMirror 2](http://codemirror.net/2/) which fits 90%-95% of your requirements *and can be expanded to fit the rest*:

- Open Source & Gratis - **Yes** *commercial support is available from the author.*
- Code Reformatting - **Yes**
- Syntax Highlighting - **Yes**
- Linux - **Yes** Cross platform JavaScript-based in-browser solution
- Offline Use - **Yes** either download the [latest release](http://codemirror.net/codemirror.zip) or clone the [git repository](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/git/codemirror) and run from that.
- Support the following languages:

  - C/C++ **Yes**
  - Java **Yes**
  - JavaScript **Yes**
  - Objective-C **Not specifically** *but [C mode](https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/) should more or less cover this and is even in the examples*
  - [Protobuf](https://codemirror.net/mode/protobuf/index.html) **Not mentioned on the web page** ***but present in the git repo***
  - HTML **Yes**
  - PHP **Yes**
  - Python **Yes**
  - Lua **Yes**
  - and hopefully some other languages I need in the future **50 languages currently supported and you can [add your own](http://codemirror.net/2/doc/manual.html#modeapi)**

*Hopefully if you add additional languages you will contribute them back to the project*

### Demo: Before autoformat

[image]

### Demo After autoformat all

[image]

Comment: it seems a good alternative,  is there a command-line interface i could use with Geany?

Answer (score 0):

*Note that pygments is a code highlighter, not a re-formatting tool, it is not intended as such.*

The python [pygments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygments/) package, when installed with:

```
pip install -U pygments
```

or on Linux:

```
sudo pip install -U pygments
```

Adds the command `pygmentize` can output to html, ***or to a colour supporting terminal***, testing on a python file, with the default output style and autodetect:

[image: screenshot]

Python & pygments are:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- pygments currently supports a number of output formats, HTML, LaTeX, RTF, SVG, all image formats that PIL supports and ANSI sequences

Checking my installed version for supported lexers gives well over **300** suported languages &/or variants which should be pleanty for most people:

```
Pygments version 2.1.3, (c) 2006-2015 by Georg Brandl.
```

### Lexers:

- abap:     ABAP (filenames *.abap, *.ABAP)
- abnf:     ABNF (filenames *.abnf)
- ada, ada95, ada2005:     Ada (filenames *.adb, *.ads, *.ada)
- adl:     ADL (filenames *.adl, *.adls, *.adlf, *.adlx)
- agda:     Agda (filenames *.agda)
- ahk, autohotkey:     autohotkey (filenames *.ahk, *.ahkl)
- alloy:     Alloy (filenames *.als)
- antlr-as, antlr-actionscript:     ANTLR With ActionScript Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-cpp:     ANTLR With CPP Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-csharp, antlr-c#:     ANTLR With C# Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-java:     ANTLR With Java Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-objc:     ANTLR With ObjectiveC Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-perl:     ANTLR With Perl Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-python:     ANTLR With Python Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr-ruby, antlr-rb:     ANTLR With Ruby Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
- antlr:     ANTLR
- apacheconf, aconf, apache:     ApacheConf (filenames .htaccess, apache.conf, apache2.conf)
- apl:     APL (filenames *.apl)
- applescript:     AppleScript (filenames *.applescript)
- arduino:     Arduino (filenames *.ino)
- as, actionscript:     ActionScript (filenames *.as)
- as3, actionscript3:     ActionScript 3 (filenames *.as)
- aspectj:     AspectJ (filenames *.aj)
- aspx-cs:     aspx-cs (filenames *.aspx, *.asax, *.ascx, *.ashx, *.asmx, *.axd)
- aspx-vb:     aspx-vb (filenames *.aspx, *.asax, *.ascx, *.ashx, *.asmx, *.axd)
- asy, asymptote:     Asymptote (filenames *.asy)
- at, ambienttalk, ambienttalk/2:     AmbientTalk (filenames *.at)
- autoit:     AutoIt (filenames *.au3)
- awk, gawk, mawk, nawk:     Awk (filenames *.awk)
- basemake:     Base Makefile
- bash, sh, ksh, shell:     Bash (filenames *.sh, *.ksh, *.bash, *.ebuild, *.eclass, *.exheres-0, *.exlib, .bashrc, bashrc, .bash_*, bash_*, PKGBUILD)
- bat, batch, dosbatch, winbatch:     Batchfile (filenames *.bat, *.cmd)
- bbcode:     BBCode
- bc:     BC (filenames *.bc)
- befunge:     Befunge (filenames *.befunge)
- blitzbasic, b3d, bplus:     BlitzBasic (filenames *.bb, *.decls)
- blitzmax, bmax:     BlitzMax (filenames *.bmx)
- bnf:     BNF (filenames *.bnf)
- boo:     Boo (filenames *.boo)
- boogie:     Boogie (filenames *.bpl)
- brainfuck, bf:     Brainfuck (filenames *.bf, *.b)
- bro:     Bro (filenames *.bro)
- bugs, winbugs, openbugs:     BUGS (filenames *.bug)
- c-objdump:     c-objdump (filenames *.c-objdump)
- c:     C (filenames *.c, *.h, *.idc)
- ca65:     ca65 assembler (filenames *.s)
- cadl:     cADL (filenames *.cadl)
- camkes, idl4:     CAmkES (filenames *.camkes, *.idl4)
- cbmbas:     CBM BASIC V2 (filenames *.bas)
- ceylon:     Ceylon (filenames *.ceylon)
- cfc:     Coldfusion CFC (filenames *.cfc)
- cfengine3, cf3:     CFEngine3 (filenames *.cf)
- cfm:     Coldfusion HTML (filenames *.cfm, *.cfml)
- cfs:     cfstatement
- chai, chaiscript:     ChaiScript (filenames *.chai)
- chapel, chpl:     Chapel (filenames *.chpl)
- cheetah, spitfire:     Cheetah (filenames *.tmpl, *.spt)
- cirru:     Cirru (filenames *.cirru)
- clay:     Clay (filenames *.clay)
- clojure, clj:     Clojure (filenames *.clj)
- clojurescript, cljs:     ClojureScript (filenames *.cljs)
- cmake:     CMake (filenames *.cmake, CMakeLists.txt)
- cobol:     COBOL (filenames *.cob, *.COB, *.cpy, *.CPY)
- cobolfree:     COBOLFree (filenames *.cbl, *.CBL)
- coffee-script, coffeescript, coffee:     CoffeeScript (filenames *.coffee)
- common-lisp, cl, lisp:     Common Lisp (filenames *.cl, *.lisp)
- componentpascal, cp:     Component Pascal (filenames *.cp, *.cps)
- console, shell-session:     Bash Session (filenames *.sh-session, *.shell-session)
- control, debcontrol:     Debian Control file (filenames control)
- coq:     Coq (filenames *.v)
- cpp, c++:     C++ (filenames *.cpp, *.hpp, *.c++, *.h++, *.cc, *.hh, *.cxx, *.hxx, *.C, *.H, *.cp, *.CPP)
- cpp-objdump, c++-objdumb, cxx-objdump:     cpp-objdump (filenames *.cpp-objdump, *.c++-objdump, *.cxx-objdump)
- cpsa:     CPSA (filenames *.cpsa)
- crmsh, pcmk:     Crmsh (filenames *.crmsh, *.pcmk)
- croc:     Croc (filenames *.croc)
- cryptol, cry:     Cryptol (filenames *.cry)
- csharp, c#:     C# (filenames *.cs)
- csound, csound-orc:     Csound Orchestra (filenames *.orc)
- csound-document, csound-csd:     Csound Document (filenames *.csd)
- csound-score, csound-sco:     Csound Score (filenames *.sco)
- css+django, css+jinja:     CSS+Django/Jinja
- css+erb, css+ruby:     CSS+Ruby
- css+genshitext, css+genshi:     CSS+Genshi Text
- css+lasso:     CSS+Lasso
- css+mako:     CSS+Mako
- css+mako:     CSS+Mako
- css+mozpreproc:     CSS+mozpreproc (filenames *.css.in)
- css+myghty:     CSS+Myghty
- css+php:     CSS+PHP
- css+smarty:     CSS+Smarty
- css:     CSS (filenames *.css)
- cucumber, gherkin:     Gherkin (filenames *.feature)
- cuda, cu:     CUDA (filenames *.cu, *.cuh)
- cypher:     Cypher (filenames *.cyp, *.cypher)
- cython, pyx, pyrex:     Cython (filenames *.pyx, *.pxd, *.pxi)
- d-objdump:     d-objdump (filenames *.d-objdump)
- d:     D (filenames *.d, *.di)
- dart:     Dart (filenames *.dart)
- delphi, pas, pascal, objectpascal:     Delphi (filenames *.pas)
- dg:     dg (filenames *.dg)
- diff, udiff:     Diff (filenames *.diff, *.patch)
- django, jinja:     Django/Jinja
- docker, dockerfile:     Docker (filenames Dockerfile, *.docker)
- doscon:     MSDOS Session
- dpatch:     Darcs Patch (filenames *.dpatch, *.darcspatch)
- dtd:     DTD (filenames *.dtd)
- duel, jbst, jsonml+bst:     Duel (filenames *.duel, *.jbst)
- dylan-console, dylan-repl:     Dylan session (filenames *.dylan-console)
- dylan-lid, lid:     DylanLID (filenames *.lid, *.hdp)
- dylan:     Dylan (filenames *.dylan, *.dyl, *.intr)
- earl-grey, earlgrey, eg:     Earl Grey (filenames *.eg)
- easytrieve:     Easytrieve (filenames *.ezt, *.mac)
- ebnf:     EBNF (filenames *.ebnf)
- ec:     eC (filenames *.ec, *.eh)
- ecl:     ECL (filenames *.ecl)
- eiffel:     Eiffel (filenames *.e)
- elixir, ex, exs:     Elixir (filenames *.ex, *.exs)
- elm:     Elm (filenames *.elm)
- emacs, elisp, emacs-lisp:     EmacsLisp (filenames *.el)
- erb:     ERB
- erl:     Erlang erl session (filenames *.erl-sh)
- erlang:     Erlang (filenames *.erl, *.hrl, *.es, *.escript)
- evoque:     Evoque (filenames *.evoque)
- ezhil:     Ezhil (filenames *.n)
- factor:     Factor (filenames *.factor)
- fan:     Fantom (filenames *.fan)
- fancy, fy:     Fancy (filenames *.fy, *.fancypack)
- felix, flx:     Felix (filenames *.flx, *.flxh)
- fish, fishshell:     Fish (filenames *.fish, *.load)
- fortran:     Fortran (filenames *.f03, *.f90, *.F03, *.F90)
- fortranfixed:     FortranFixed (filenames *.f, *.F)
- foxpro, vfp, clipper, xbase:     FoxPro (filenames *.PRG, *.prg)
- fsharp:     FSharp (filenames *.fs, *.fsi)
- gap:     GAP (filenames *.g, *.gd, *.gi, *.gap)
- gas, asm:     GAS (filenames *.s, *.S)
- genshi, kid, xml+genshi, xml+kid:     Genshi (filenames *.kid)
- genshitext:     Genshi Text
- glsl:     GLSL (filenames *.vert, *.frag, *.geo)
- gnuplot:     Gnuplot (filenames *.plot, *.plt)
- go:     Go (filenames *.go)
- golo:     Golo (filenames *.golo)
- gooddata-cl:     GoodData-CL (filenames *.gdc)
- gosu:     Gosu (filenames *.gs, *.gsx, *.gsp, *.vark)
- groff, nroff, man:     Groff (filenames *.[1234567], *.man)
- groovy:     Groovy (filenames *.groovy, *.gradle)
- gst:     Gosu Template (filenames *.gst)
- haml:     Haml (filenames *.haml)
- handlebars:     Handlebars
- haskell, hs:     Haskell (filenames *.hs)
- haxeml, hxml:     Hxml (filenames *.hxml)
- hexdump:     Hexdump
- html+cheetah, html+spitfire, htmlcheetah:     HTML+Cheetah
- html+django, html+jinja, htmldjango:     HTML+Django/Jinja
- html+evoque:     HTML+Evoque (filenames *.html)
- html+genshi, html+kid:     HTML+Genshi
- html+handlebars:     HTML+Handlebars (filenames *.handlebars, *.hbs)
- html+lasso:     HTML+Lasso
- html+mako:     HTML+Mako
- html+mako:     HTML+Mako
- html+myghty:     HTML+Myghty
- html+php:     HTML+PHP (filenames *.phtml)
- html+smarty:     HTML+Smarty
- html+twig:     HTML+Twig (filenames *.twig)
- html+velocity:     HTML+Velocity
- html:     HTML (filenames *.html, *.htm, *.xhtml, *.xslt)
- http:     HTTP
- hx, haxe, hxsl:     Haxe (filenames *.hx, *.hxsl)
- hybris, hy:     Hybris (filenames *.hy, *.hyb)
- hylang:     Hy (filenames *.hy)
- i6t:     Inform 6 template (filenames *.i6t)
- idl:     IDL (filenames *.pro)
- idris, idr:     Idris (filenames *.idr)
- iex:     Elixir iex session
- igor, igorpro:     Igor (filenames *.ipf)
- inform6, i6:     Inform 6 (filenames *.inf)
- inform7, i7:     Inform 7 (filenames *.ni, *.i7x)
- ini, cfg, dosini:     INI (filenames *.ini, *.cfg, *.inf)
- io:     Io (filenames *.io)
- ioke, ik:     Ioke (filenames *.ik)
- ipython2, ipython:     IPython
- ipython3:     IPython3
- ipythonconsole:     IPython console session
- irc:     IRC logs (filenames *.weechatlog)
- isabelle:     Isabelle (filenames *.thy)
- j:     J (filenames *.ijs)
- jade:     Jade (filenames *.jade)
- jags:     JAGS (filenames *.jag, *.bug)
- jasmin, jasminxt:     Jasmin (filenames *.j)
- java:     Java (filenames *.java)
- javascript+mozpreproc:     Javascript+mozpreproc (filenames *.js.in)
- jcl:     JCL (filenames *.jcl)
- jlcon:     Julia console
- js+cheetah, javascript+cheetah, js+spitfire, javascript+spitfire:     JavaScript+Cheetah
- js+django, javascript+django, js+jinja, javascript+jinja:     JavaScript+Django/Jinja
- js+erb, javascript+erb, js+ruby, javascript+ruby:     JavaScript+Ruby
- js+genshitext, js+genshi, javascript+genshitext, javascript+genshi:     JavaScript+Genshi Text
- js+lasso, javascript+lasso:     JavaScript+Lasso
- js+mako, javascript+mako:     JavaScript+Mako
- js+mako, javascript+mako:     JavaScript+Mako
- js+myghty, javascript+myghty:     JavaScript+Myghty
- js+php, javascript+php:     JavaScript+PHP
- js+smarty, javascript+smarty:     JavaScript+Smarty
- js, javascript:     JavaScript (filenames *.js, *.jsm)
- json:     JSON (filenames *.json)
- jsonld, json-ld:     JSON-LD (filenames *.jsonld)
- jsp:     Java Server Page (filenames *.jsp)
- julia, jl:     Julia (filenames *.jl)
- kal:     Kal (filenames *.kal)
- kconfig, menuconfig, linux-config, kernel-config:     Kconfig (filenames Kconfig, *Config.in*, external.in*, standard-modules.in)
- koka:     Koka (filenames *.kk, *.kki)
- kotlin:     Kotlin (filenames *.kt)
- lagda, literate-agda:     Literate Agda (filenames *.lagda)
- lasso, lassoscript:     Lasso (filenames *.lasso, *.lasso[89])
- lcry, literate-cryptol, lcryptol:     Literate Cryptol (filenames *.lcry)
- lean:     Lean (filenames *.lean)
- less:     LessCss (filenames *.less)
- lhs, literate-haskell, lhaskell:     Literate Haskell (filenames *.lhs)
- lidr, literate-idris, lidris:     Literate Idris (filenames *.lidr)
- lighty, lighttpd:     Lighttpd configuration file
- limbo:     Limbo (filenames *.b)
- liquid:     liquid (filenames *.liquid)
- live-script, livescript:     LiveScript (filenames *.ls)
- llvm:     LLVM (filenames *.ll)
- logos:     Logos (filenames *.x, *.xi, *.xm, *.xmi)
- logtalk:     Logtalk (filenames *.lgt, *.logtalk)
- lsl:     LSL (filenames *.lsl)
- lua:     Lua (filenames *.lua, *.wlua)
- make, makefile, mf, bsdmake:     Makefile (filenames *.mak, *.mk, Makefile, makefile, Makefile.*, GNUmakefile)
- mako:     Mako (filenames *.mao)
- mako:     Mako (filenames *.mao)
- maql:     MAQL (filenames *.maql)
- mask:     Mask (filenames *.mask)
- mason:     Mason (filenames *.m, *.mhtml, *.mc, *.mi, autohandler, dhandler)
- mathematica, mma, nb:     Mathematica (filenames *.nb, *.cdf, *.nbp, *.ma)
- matlab:     Matlab (filenames *.m)
- matlabsession:     Matlab session
- minid:     MiniD
- modelica:     Modelica (filenames *.mo)
- modula2, m2:     Modula-2 (filenames *.def, *.mod)
- monkey:     Monkey (filenames *.monkey)
- moocode, moo:     MOOCode (filenames *.moo)
- moon, moonscript:     MoonScript (filenames *.moon)
- mozhashpreproc:     mozhashpreproc
- mozpercentpreproc:     mozpercentpreproc
- mql, mq4, mq5, mql4, mql5:     MQL (filenames *.mq4, *.mq5, *.mqh)
- mscgen, msc:     Mscgen (filenames *.msc)
- mupad:     MuPAD (filenames *.mu)
- mxml:     MXML (filenames *.mxml)
- myghty:     Myghty (filenames *.myt, autodelegate)
- mysql:     MySQL
- nasm:     NASM (filenames *.asm, *.ASM)
- nemerle:     Nemerle (filenames *.n)
- nesc:     nesC (filenames *.nc)
- newlisp:     NewLisp (filenames *.lsp, *.nl)
- newspeak:     Newspeak (filenames *.ns2)
- nginx:     Nginx configuration file
- nimrod, nim:     Nimrod (filenames *.nim, *.nimrod)
- nit:     Nit (filenames *.nit)
- nixos, nix:     Nix (filenames *.nix)
- nsis, nsi, nsh:     NSIS (filenames *.nsi, *.nsh)
- numpy:     NumPy
- objdump-nasm:     objdump-nasm (filenames *.objdump-intel)
- objdump:     objdump (filenames *.objdump)
- objective-c++, objectivec++, obj-c++, objc++:     Objective-C++ (filenames *.mm, *.hh)
- objective-c, objectivec, obj-c, objc:     Objective-C (filenames *.m, *.h)
- objective-j, objectivej, obj-j, objj:     Objective-J (filenames *.j)
- ocaml:     OCaml (filenames *.ml, *.mli, *.mll, *.mly)
- octave:     Octave (filenames *.m)
- odin:     ODIN (filenames *.odin)
- ooc:     Ooc (filenames *.ooc)
- opa:     Opa (filenames *.opa)
- openedge, abl, progress:     OpenEdge ABL (filenames *.p, *.cls)
- pacmanconf:     PacmanConf (filenames pacman.conf)
- pan:     Pan (filenames *.pan)
- parasail:     ParaSail (filenames *.psi, *.psl)
- pawn:     Pawn (filenames *.p, *.pwn, *.inc)
- perl, pl:     Perl (filenames *.pl, *.pm, *.t)
- perl6, pl6:     Perl6 (filenames *.pl, *.pm, *.nqp, *.p6, *.6pl, *.p6l, *.pl6, *.6pm, *.p6m, *.pm6, *.t)
- php, php3, php4, php5:     PHP (filenames *.php, *.php[345], *.inc)
- pig:     Pig (filenames *.pig)
- pike:     Pike (filenames *.pike, *.pmod)
- pkgconfig:     PkgConfig (filenames *.pc)
- plpgsql:     PL/pgSQL
- postgresql, postgres:     PostgreSQL SQL dialect
- postscript, postscr:     PostScript (filenames *.ps, *.eps)
- pot, po:     Gettext Catalog (filenames *.pot, *.po)
- pov:     POVRay (filenames *.pov, *.inc)
- powershell, posh, ps1, psm1:     PowerShell (filenames *.ps1, *.psm1)
- praat:     Praat (filenames *.praat, *.proc, *.psc)
- prolog:     Prolog (filenames *.ecl, *.prolog, *.pro, *.pl)
- properties, jproperties:     Properties (filenames *.properties)
- protobuf, proto:     Protocol Buffer (filenames *.proto)
- ps1con:     PowerShell Session
- psql, postgresql-console, postgres-console:     PostgreSQL console (psql)
- puppet:     Puppet (filenames *.pp)
- py3tb:     Python 3.0 Traceback (filenames *.py3tb)
- pycon:     Python console session
- pypylog, pypy:     PyPy Log (filenames *.pypylog)
- pytb:     Python Traceback (filenames *.pytb)
- python, py, sage:     Python (filenames *.py, *.pyw, *.sc, SConstruct, SConscript, *.tac, *.sage)
- python3, py3:     Python 3
- qbasic, basic:     QBasic (filenames *.BAS, *.bas)
- qml, qbs:     QML (filenames *.qml, *.qbs)
- qvto, qvt:     QVTO (filenames *.qvto)
- racket, rkt:     Racket (filenames *.rkt, *.rktd, *.rktl)
- ragel-c:     Ragel in C Host (filenames *.rl)
- ragel-cpp:     Ragel in CPP Host (filenames *.rl)
- ragel-d:     Ragel in D Host (filenames *.rl)
- ragel-em:     Embedded Ragel (filenames *.rl)
- ragel-java:     Ragel in Java Host (filenames *.rl)
- ragel-objc:     Ragel in Objective C Host (filenames *.rl)
- ragel-ruby, ragel-rb:     Ragel in Ruby Host (filenames *.rl)
- ragel:     Ragel
- raw:     Raw token data
- rb, ruby, duby:     Ruby (filenames *.rb, *.rbw, Rakefile, *.rake, *.gemspec, *.rbx, *.duby, Gemfile)
- rbcon, irb:     Ruby irb session
- rconsole, rout:     RConsole (filenames *.Rout)
- rd:     Rd (filenames *.Rd)
- rebol:     REBOL (filenames *.r, *.r3, *.reb)
- red, red/system:     Red (filenames *.red, *.reds)
- redcode:     Redcode (filenames *.cw)
- registry:     reg (filenames *.reg)
- resource, resourcebundle:     ResourceBundle (filenames *.txt)
- rexx, arexx:     Rexx (filenames *.rexx, *.rex, *.rx, *.arexx)
- rhtml, html+erb, html+ruby:     RHTML (filenames *.rhtml)
- roboconf-graph:     Roboconf Graph (filenames *.graph)
- roboconf-instances:     Roboconf Instances (filenames *.instances)
- robotframework:     RobotFramework (filenames *.txt, *.robot)
- rql:     RQL (filenames *.rql)
- rsl:     RSL (filenames *.rsl)
- rst, rest, restructuredtext:     reStructuredText (filenames *.rst, *.rest)
- rts, trafficscript:     TrafficScript (filenames *.rts)
- rust:     Rust (filenames *.rs, *.rs.in)
- sass:     Sass (filenames *.sass)
- sc, supercollider:     SuperCollider (filenames *.sc, *.scd)
- scala:     Scala (filenames *.scala)
- scaml:     Scaml (filenames *.scaml)
- scheme, scm:     Scheme (filenames *.scm, *.ss)
- scilab:     Scilab (filenames *.sci, *.sce, *.tst)
- scss:     SCSS (filenames *.scss)
- shen:     Shen (filenames *.shen)
- slim:     Slim (filenames *.slim)
- smali:     Smali (filenames *.smali)
- smalltalk, squeak, st:     Smalltalk (filenames *.st)
- smarty:     Smarty (filenames *.tpl)
- sml:     Standard ML (filenames *.sml, *.sig, *.fun)
- snobol:     Snobol (filenames *.snobol)
- sourceslist, sources.list, debsources:     Debian Sourcelist (filenames sources.list)
- sp:     SourcePawn (filenames *.sp)
- sparql:     SPARQL (filenames *.rq, *.sparql)
- spec:     RPMSpec (filenames *.spec)
- splus, s, r:     S (filenames *.S, *.R, .Rhistory, .Rprofile, .Renviron)
- sql:     SQL (filenames *.sql)
- sqlite3:     sqlite3con (filenames *.sqlite3-console)
- squidconf, squid.conf, squid:     SquidConf (filenames squid.conf)
- ssp:     Scalate Server Page (filenames *.ssp)
- stan:     Stan (filenames *.stan)
- swift:     Swift (filenames *.swift)
- swig:     SWIG (filenames *.swg, *.i)
- systemverilog, sv:     systemverilog (filenames *.sv, *.svh)
- tads3:     TADS 3 (filenames *.t)
- tap:     TAP (filenames *.tap)
- tcl:     Tcl (filenames *.tcl, *.rvt)
- tcsh, csh:     Tcsh (filenames *.tcsh, *.csh)
- tcshcon:     Tcsh Session
- tea:     Tea (filenames *.tea)
- termcap:     Termcap (filenames termcap, termcap.src)
- terminfo:     Terminfo (filenames terminfo, terminfo.src)
- terraform, tf:     Terraform (filenames *.tf)
- tex, latex:     TeX (filenames *.tex, *.aux, *.toc)
- text:     Text only (filenames *.txt)
- thrift:     Thrift (filenames *.thrift)
- todotxt:     Todotxt (filenames todo.txt, *.todotxt)
- trac-wiki, moin:     MoinMoin/Trac Wiki markup
- treetop:     Treetop (filenames *.treetop, *.tt)
- ts, typescript:     TypeScript (filenames *.ts)
- turtle:     Turtle (filenames *.ttl)
- twig:     Twig
- urbiscript:     UrbiScript (filenames *.u)
- vala, vapi:     Vala (filenames *.vala, *.vapi)
- vb.net, vbnet:     VB.net (filenames *.vb, *.bas)
- vctreestatus:     VCTreeStatus
- velocity:     Velocity (filenames *.vm, *.fhtml)
- verilog, v:     verilog (filenames *.v)
- vgl:     VGL (filenames *.rpf)
- vhdl:     vhdl (filenames *.vhdl, *.vhd)
- vim:     VimL (filenames *.vim, .vimrc, .exrc, .gvimrc, _vimrc, _exrc, _gvimrc, vimrc, gvimrc)
- x10, xten:     X10 (filenames *.x10)
- xml+cheetah, xml+spitfire:     XML+Cheetah
- xml+django, xml+jinja:     XML+Django/Jinja
- xml+erb, xml+ruby:     XML+Ruby
- xml+evoque:     XML+Evoque (filenames *.xml)
- xml+lasso:     XML+Lasso
- xml+mako:     XML+Mako
- xml+mako:     XML+Mako
- xml+myghty:     XML+Myghty
- xml+php:     XML+PHP
- xml+smarty:     XML+Smarty
- xml+velocity:     XML+Velocity
- xml:     XML (filenames *.xml, *.xsl, *.rss, *.xslt, *.xsd, *.wsdl, *.wsf)
- xquery, xqy, xq, xql, xqm:     XQuery (filenames *.xqy, *.xquery, *.xq, *.xql, *.xqm)
- xslt:     XSLT (filenames *.xsl, *.xslt, *.xpl)
- xtend:     Xtend (filenames *.xtend)
- xul+mozpreproc:     XUL+mozpreproc (filenames *.xul.in)
- yaml+jinja, salt, sls:     YAML+Jinja (filenames *.sls)
- yaml:     YAML (filenames *.yaml, *.yml)
- zephir:     Zephir (filenames *.zep)

Comment: Python is a bad example here, since Python relies on indentation as part of the syntax. Can it really fulfill OP's requirement of formatting a left aligned Java code that has 10 statements with semicolons `;` per line and braces in wrong places?

Comment: @Thomas: where did OP *require* formatting "left aligned Java... etc."? [I agree that's a good thing in general but SR isn't about inventing other people's requirements.]

Comment: @IraBaxter: in the title "beautify" and "pretty-print". Pretty-printed XML e.g. has line-breaks and proper indentation. Also "reformat the source code". In Eclipse, a reformat does exactly this: put one statement per line, put braces at the right place and indent the code. If you don't have left-aligned Java code you don't need such a tool ;-)

Comment: I've tried `pygmentize` as suggested, but like `source-highlight` it does not reformat the code, it just adds color highlighting (tried with C and Python source code files)..

Answer (score 0):

Our [Source Code Formatter family](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/) covers a broad range of languages.  They are based on accurate (specific to dialect) source language parsing to ASTs and regeneration of code from the ASTs.  This kind of reformatting never breaks the reformatted code with respect to compilability or functionality. (There are string-hacking formatters that can break your code; these look great until you find yourself debugging formatted code that used to work).

The reformatting handles "left-aligned Java with badly placed { }" (and the analogs for other languages) as suggested as a reasonable requirement in a commment to one of the other answers.

They are necessarily built as separate entities because

- there's a lot of them, and this make maintenance by our team practical
- the languages they process evolve at different rates
- they require different parsing capabilities (e.g. C and C++ require some unusual support to handle preprocessor directives, COBOL has area constraints, Python uses funny indentation, ...)

How this addresses OP's "requirements":

- Cover many languages (All of OP's specific list excluding ProtoBuf, maybe someday)
- Must install them separately; however, they all have consistent styles and interfaces, so it is not the same experience as installing N different formatters from N different providers, each with its own installation/configuration/command line variations.
- They are run in a consistent way and they are scriptable.  Operator can format from a file to another, or from a file to standard out, or one can format a large set of files at once.
- Operates on Windows natively and on Linux under Wine.  In the latter cause, the launch scripts are sh commands and the presence of Wine is not noticed by the caller
- Closed source (if acquired as Formatters; one can obtain the source of each formatter by acquiring our general program transformation product)
- Not requested but extremely useful: these formatters understand a wide variety of character encodings, and can even switch from the read-encoding to a different encoding as printed.

Since these formatters are my company's products, don't take my response here as a recommendation. I'm simply documenting their existence.

Comment: these looks like Windows commercial products, i've asked for free Linux-compatible alternatives.

Comment: What you said was you'd prefer to avoid closed source.  And the software does run under Linux, even if you don't like how.   And I happen to believe that solutions of this kind are pretty hard to find.